# yield to generate permutation of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I am new to python3.x (and yield) and I am trying to generate permutation of numbers without using itertools. I want to generate it on the fly so I have used `yield` keyword but I am not getting any output here.

```
def nextPermutation(self, nums):
    permute_generator = self.permuteHelper(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1)
    for item in permute_generator:
        print(item)

def permuteHelper(self, a, l, r):
    if l == r:
        yield a
    else:
        for i in range(l, r + 1):
            a[l], a[r] = a[r], a[l]
            self.permuteHelper(a, l + 1, r)
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]
```

What should I need to change here?

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive case never yields anything because you don't do anything with the value of the recursive call. For a recursive generator, you probably want to use `yield from`. I'm not sure that adding that will make your code generate the permutations you expect, but it should yield some values at least.

```
def permuteHelper(self, a, l, r):
    if l == r:
        yield a
    else:
        for i in range(l, r + 1):
            a[l], a[r] = a[r], a[l]
            yield from self.permuteHelper(a, l + 1, r)    # add yield from here!
            a[l], a[i] = a[i], a[l]
```